# What is the single word for the select\deselect

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the single word for the select\deselect. I can think one word "Manage" but not sure how relative it is to select and deselect really.

Please don't ask for context as it confuses people then.

Comment: Is it within a frame or section that makes it clear that what it is doing is to objects. e.g. Objects > Manage. i.e. that it does its thing to objects is a given?

Comment: I am guessing that you want to design a user interface. If so then an existing convention may help you. I am not sure but you could try http://ux.stackexchange.com/ or even http://stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: @EleventhDoctor nope, I just want to know if there's any single word for select or deselect, we provide context for understanding not for wanna be answers :(

Comment: I think @Margana has cracked it with *toggle*.

Comment: It simply has to be said: it's a HUGE PITY that anyone voted to close, or voted down, this excellent question. If you thought there was "no answer" or it's a "silly question" - perhaps think again about how is silly, as Margana has givne the exact answer to this **excellent question**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's one switch which alternates between two states in response to the same action (as an on/off button) it's called a **toggle**.

> computers : a setting that can be switched between two different
>   options by pressing a single key, making a single choice from a menu,
>   etc. [*- Merriam Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toggle)

Comment: I was about to give this as the answer. +1

Comment: Perfect answer to a superb question.  Here's a puzzle *I am as to positive negative as toggle is to select deselect. What am I?*

Comment: "I am to positive/negative as toggle is to select/deselect. What am I? Answer: n times -1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think **Option** as Opt one of the object or **Choice** as Choose one of the object can fit here.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I feel that a button which selects one option from a choice of two (mutually exlcusive) states is called a ***[switch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/switch)***.

I can find no *single* definition of ***switch*** which declares this property, however combining two common definitions does grant this meaning:

> 1. An exchange or swap
> 2. (Electrical Engineering) a mechanical, electrical, electronic, or optical device for opening or closing a circuit or for diverting energy from one part of a circuit to another

Both sourced from thefreedictionary.com, itself citing Collins English Dictionary in each case.

Answer (score 0):

On Web pages and the like, such a thing is called a **[checkbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox)**.